# Changes applied to SD Card won't stick after unmounting

Tags: sd-card

My friend recently asked me to help her with her SD card. When I tried to read it, I found out that it has corrupted partition table.  So, I cleaned it up and then tried to recreate partition table.

Here's the interesting part comes in:

When I do something to the SD card (create partition table, modify something) and I apply these changes, everything works;  I can copy files between card and PC without problem.

But the moment I unmount it, all changes are lost. Same when I format the card from phone recovery (TWRP).

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the device is locked.  Does the card support that functionality?

Comment: I don't know who deleted my answer but simply put: your card is broken, and I can say that based on personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

Try another SD card or that into another card reader. There is a good chance one of them are broken.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience of this kind of situation that card is most probably damaged . The card report success to every write operation done on it. Thus the OS thinks everythink goes well and no error reported. In order to speed up operations on the card the OS caches  partition table, accessed data, file/folder information. This caching made the feel of data change such as deletion of existing files and folders, creation of new files and folders. The cache is flushed during the removal of the card and new one is made on insertion of it. At the generation of new cache data from card is fetched. As the changes are not made to the card as it's damaged old data is obtained. That why you feel reverting effect on the data on reinsertion of card.

Comment: So, I should just tell my friend, that she should buy a new SD card and throw it to trash? (personally, after spending 3 days on it, I would first throw it to some corrosive acid and then smash it with baseball bat...:D)

Comment: You can use it as a  backup device, if any valuable data on it. You destroyed it. No more time killing. :-)